# Python strings within lists

Tags: python, string, list

I did not seem to find anyone asking this same question, but if it's already out there then I apologize and would appreciate a link.

For the question.
currently working with this list:

```
nouns = ['house','bee','ducks','blouse','cars']
```

I'm trying to make a program that changes words in the plural to singular and words in the singular to plural. I'm intending to try and change the list by using index numbers, something like:

```
for index, word in enumerate(nouns):
if word[-1] is 'e':
  print nouns[index]==word[-1]+'s'
    print nouns
```

I'm still very new to Python, but currently stuck. Any kind of help or hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: You know that `word[-1]` is just the last letter right?

Comment: It looks like the indentation is wrong, the `if` statement should be indented to the right

Comment: Also `print nouns[index]==word[-1]+'s'` should not have a double equals sign (`==`) as that is a comparison operator, not assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nouns = ['house','bee','ducks','blouse','cars']
for index, word in enumerate(nouns):
    if word[-1] == 'e':
        # if this word ends with e, add s
        nouns[index] = word+'s'
    elif word[-1] == 's':
        # if this word ends with s, remove last char
        nouns[index] = word[:-1]
print nouns
```

Note that this works for the particular list that you provided, but cannot grantee other collection of words because of plurals like `men`

Comment: "Note that this works for the particular list that you provided" ... exactly. If you really wanted a program that really converts between singular and plural, you're going to need some sort of dictionary/conversion table/etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
nouns = ['house','bee','ducks','blouse','cars']

plurals = [x + 's' if x.endswith('e') else x for x in nouns]
```

Comment: `ducks` has to change to  `duck`, because he/she basically wants to toggle function

Comment: ahh... yes this only changes it to plural